# Передача коллекции коллекций в TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, коллекции, binding

Я думаю название уже звучит глупо, но давайте разберемся. Суть такова, что мне в столбец DataGrid'а нужно передать коллекцию коллекций, но не просто коллекцию, а вывести все ее элементы. Сейчас объясню. Есть класс Word и класс MeaningGroup

```
public class Word
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<MeaningGroup> MeaningGroups { get; set; }
}
public class MeaningGroup
{
    public List<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
    public List<string> Acronyms { get; set; }
}
```

И вот такая разметка в xaml

```
    <Grid>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Words}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ListColumn" Header="Synonym and acronyms">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Synonyms}"/>
                                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Acronyms}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

и в качестве ItemsSource передаем следующую коллекцию:

```
        Word word1 = new Word() { Name = "word1",MeaningGroups = new List<MeaningGroup>() {group1, group2}};
        Word word2 = new Word() { Name = "word2", MeaningGroups = new List<MeaningGroup>() { group1, group2 } };
        Word word3 = new Word() { Name = "word3", MeaningGroups = new List<MeaningGroup>() { group1, group2} };
        Word word4 = new Word() { Name = "word4", MeaningGroups = new List<MeaningGroup>() { group1, group2 } };

        Words = new List<Word> {word1, word2, word3, word4};
```

В первый столбец мы передаем название, что сделать нетрудно забиндив Name, но вот что делать со столбцом, в который мы передаем List? Надо сделать так, чтобы в данный столбец (`"ListColumn"`) мы передавали список MeaningGroup, в котором чтобы group1 и group2 были на разных строках, что я и сделал, добавив два текстблока. Нужно чтобы в первый текстблок передавались все элементы из коллекции group1, а во второй текстблок передавались все элементы из коллекции group2. Если я плохо объяснил, то попробую составить краткий план:

1. Передать в `DataGrid` коллекцию `List<Word> Words`
2. В столбец `ListColumn`передавать `List<MeaningGroup>`, состоящий из `group1` и `group2`
3. В первый `TextBlock` передать все элементы из коллекции `group1`, во второй `TextBlock` передать все элементы из коллекции `group2`.

Я, может, и сам разберусь, но мне нужна помощь в том, как вообще в текстблок передать коллекцию элементов , чтобы он вывел у себя каждый элемент (еще и желательно бы с пробелом) т.е например если мы передаем ему коллекцию `List<string> group1` с элементами {"Курица", "Баклажан", "Сосиска"} чтобы его текст был "Курица баклажан сосика"?

Comment: Что мешает в стиле столбца использовать элемент, который может работать с коллекцией? Например ItemsControl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По сути тут два варианта:

1. Отображать коллекцию так, как положено. Для этого в WPF существуют элементы `ItemsControl`, которые легко настраиваются так, как вам нужно. Я не буду особо вдаваться в подробности что да как, просто покажу как это использовать на вашем примере:

   ```
   <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ListColumn" Header="Synonym and acronyms">
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MeaningGroups}">
                       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                               <StackPanel>
                                   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}">
                                       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                               <WrapPanel/>
                                           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                           <DataTemplate>
                                               <TextBlock Margin="3,3,3,3" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                           </DataTemplate>
                                       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                   </ItemsControl>
                                   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Acronyms}">
                                       <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                               <WrapPanel/>
                                           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                           <DataTemplate>
                                               <TextBlock Margin="3,3,3,3" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                           </DataTemplate>
                                       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                   </ItemsControl>
                               </StackPanel>
                           </DataTemplate>
                       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                   </ItemsControl>
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   ```

То есть мы в ячейке сделали `ItemsControl`, который привязали к `MeaningGroups` и дальше под каждую коллекцию создали еще по одному `ItemsControl` со своим шаблоном (отступ), а также с расположением элементов в ряд (с помощью `WrapPanel`, либо любой другой). Как видите код повторяется и не очень удобен, поэтому все нужное стоит вынести в отдельный стиль и его уже использовать.

2. Преобразовывать коллекцию в `string`. Тут вариантов уйма, решайте сами что и как вам будет удобней. Можно создать конвертер; можно создать отдельно свойство, где в `get` будет выдаваться нужный текст; а можно и вовсе переопределить `.ToString` и там уже вывести что нужно. Я покажу вариант с доп. свойствами:

   - Свойства:

     ```
     public string SynonymsString => Synonyms != null ? string.Join(" ", Synonyms) : null;
     public string AcronymsString => Acronyms != null ? string.Join(" ", Acronyms) : null;
     ```
   - XAML:

     ```
     <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="ListColumn" Header="Synonym and acronyms">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel>
                     <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MeaningGroups}">
                         <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                             <DataTemplate>
                                 <StackPanel>
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding SynonymsString}"/>
                                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding AcronymsString}"/>
                                 </StackPanel>
                             </DataTemplate>
                         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl>
                 </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     ```

В общем вариантов решения этой задачи уйма, выбирайте свой. Удачи!